# Electron app performance: blocking thread with ipcRenderer.sendSync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have a music player built with Electron.

I am having some performance / process blocking that I didn't expect. I am trying to do some background processes for heavy IO operations. (determining songs duration and album covers)

I am doing this by calling methods through the electron.remote module.
I have noticed that the app didn't do these things asynchronously somehow.

I have been running the performance tool to check and saw the click handler taking a huge time.

[image: the click handler]

Digging deeper I found that `ipcRenderer.sendSync` is called.

[image]

There is a warning about `sendSync` blocking nature in [Electron Docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-renderer.md#ipcrenderersendsyncchannel-arg1-arg2-). But, my own code does not call it. So I suspect the remote module or something else in my code causing `sendSync` to be called.

The entire app code is on Github but [here is an example of electron.remote usage](https://github.com/AoDev/kaiku-music-player/blob/feat/song-duration/app/lib/mediaLibrary/mediaLibrary.js#L264).

The gist is something like this:

```
import {remote} from 'electron'

const fs = remote.require('fs')
const mm = remote.require('musicmetadata')

// read song file, IO
function readMetadata (filePath) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    mm(stream, {duration: true}, function (err, metadata) {
      // ...
    })
  })
}

// get metadata for an array of songs
async function refreshSongsDuration (songs) {
  const songsMetadata = await Promise.all(songs.map((song) => readMetadata(song.filePath)))

  return songs.map((song, index) => {
    song.duration = songsMetadata[index].duration
    return song
  })
}
```

Then in a click handler I'll have something like this:

```
playArtist (artistID) {
  const songs = this.library.getArtistSongs(artistID)
  this.playlist.setSongs(songs)
  musicPlayer.play()

  const shouldGetDuration = songs.some((song) => song.duration === 0)

  // This is expected to be asynchronous and non blocking.
  if (shouldGetDuration) {
    mediaLibrary.refreshSongsDuration(songs)
      .then((updatedSongs) => {
        this.playlist.set('songs', updatedSongs)
      })
  }
}
```

So, I guess the simple question here is, what am I doing wrong causing these blocking processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md#remote-objects

> Each object (including functions) returned by the remote module represents an object in the main process (we call it a remote object or remote function). When you invoke methods of a remote object, call a remote function, or create a new object with the remote constructor (function), you are actually sending synchronous inter-process messages.

every remote module is sync in nature.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Then how can I handle such things asynchronously? I have to stop using the remote module and use ipcMain, ipcRenderer only, such as described here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main?

Comment: Yes, that's built-in supported way from Electron.

Comment: Just be aware that many of the `ipcRenderer/Main` methods will also block the main/renderer processes